# AngularJs enabling and disabling dynamic behaviour not working as excepted

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJs , so please bare with for silly questions. I am trying to implement a dynamic behavior for button on click event , but its working as excepted , is it because of some scope ?

Here is my Html code :

```
 <html ng-app="loopModule">
 <head>
 <title>Looping Example</title> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/LoopController.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="LoopController">   
  <strong>Using NG-DISABLED :</strong><br/>
  <button ng-disabled="isButtonDisabled" >I am Button</button>
  <button ng-click="disableButton(isButtonDisabled)" >Click Me</button>
 <br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller :

```
var eventDrivenSample = angular.module('eventDrivenPackage', []);
loopModule.controller('LoopController' , 
function loopController($scope ,$window){
   $scope.isButtonDisabled = true;

   $scope.disableButton =function(isButtonDisabled){
          if(isButtonDisabled)
                  isButtonDisabled = false;
           else
             isButtonDisabled = true;
          return isButtonDisabled;
   }
 }
);
```

The problem is button is not enabling when i click on "Click me" button but if i replace 
Click Me 
with this 
    Click Me

then button is getting enabled as excepted. What am i doing wrong?. Any body please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller to:

```
var eventDrivenSample = angular.module('eventDrivenPackage', []);
loopModule.controller('LoopController' , 
function loopController($scope ,$window){
   $scope.isButtonDisabled = true;
   $scope.disableButton = function(isButtonDisabled){
     $scope.isButtonDisabled = !isButtonDisabled;
   }
 }
);
```

Your mistake was that you don't set the value of the scope property (i.e. `$scope.isButtonDisabled`) but to the method `disableButton` parameter, which isn't being watched by AngularJS.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/fahacasi/1/edit)